# What is the correct way to implement Struct abstraction in Go?

Tags: inheritance, go

I'm having some issues understanding Go's struct inheritance. I'm trying to do somewhat of an abstraction for an object type. See the example code below:

```
package main

type Animal struct{}
type Dog struct {
    Animal
    Color string
}

type Person struct {
    Name string
    Age  int
    Pet  *Animal
}

func main() {
    dog := &Dog{Color: "brown"}
    tom := &Person{Name: "Tom", Age: 13, Pet: dog}
}
```

This is causing a compilation error:

> cannot use dog (type *Dog) as type *Animal in field value

What is the correct way to go about doing an abstraction like this? Is it possible in Go?

End goal for the example would be to have different types of Pets - Dog, Cat, Hamser, etc. Then be able to store that into a struct expecting type Animal.

To visualize, something like:

```
type Person struct {
    Name string
    Age  int
    Pet  *Dog OR *Cat OR *Hamster
}
```

[Go Playground Link](https://play.golang.org/p/KVSzbZxjh1)

Comment: And then do what? please elaborate

Comment: Well the actual implementation of this is in a web backend. It's an attempt to have a generic JSON response back to the client with `Results` as type `[]*DataModel` where that could be filled with different types of data types, depending on the request.

Comment: Go does not have struct inheritance, it does however support struct embedding, which are two very different things. A struct of type `Foo` that embeds a struct of type `Bar` cannot be used in places where `Bar` is expected. All `Foo` gets from embedding `Bar` is access to `Bar`'s fields and methods. So `Foo` IS NOT `Bar`, it only "knows about" `Bar`, while `Bar` does not even know, or care, about `Foo` at all.

Comment: This cleared up the questions I had surrounding embedding, thank you!

Comment: "What is the correct way to go about doing an abstraction like this?" No, it is not. Go has no notion of inheritance and you should not try to model your code in a inheritance-based style. "Is it possible in Go?" No. You would use interfaces instead of parent classes.

Comment: Just to give you a clue as to how go's embedding works: it's composition, not inheritance. You could try and write: `tom := &Person{Name: "Tom", Age: 13, Pet: &dog.Animal}`. your `dog` variable _contains_ a full `Animal`, but it is *not* an animal. It's is own type that consists of its own fields (`Colour`), and an `Animal`, whatever that type might be

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two working samples:

1- Try [this](https://play.golang.org/p/hg_4K61NLu):

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type Animal interface {
    color() string
}
type Dog struct {
    Color string
}

func (d Dog) color() string {
    return d.Color
}

type Person struct {
    Name string
    Age  int
    Pet  Animal
}

func main() {
    dog := &Dog{Color: "brown"}
    tom := &Person{Name: "Tom", Age: 13, Pet: dog}
    fmt.Println(tom.Pet.color())
}
```

---

2- Try [this](https://play.golang.org/p/zR5opxAkrv):

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type Animal struct{}
type Dog struct {
    Animal
    Color string
}

type Person struct {
    Name string
    Age  int
    Pet  interface{}
}

func main() {
    dog := &Dog{Color: "brown"}
    tom := &Person{Name: "Tom", Age: 13, Pet: dog}
    fmt.Println(tom.Name)
}
```

Comment: I was trying to avoid using an empty interface for the reason that you could pass anything into it. For example, the `Person` could end up with a `Bicycle` as his `Pet`.

Comment: So you may use(1) based on functionality of Object. Is this Good for your case?

Comment: Thank you, your solution helped me find the bug in my code. I was incorrectly setting Pet to `*Animal` which is a pointer to the interface rather than having it be of the interface type itself. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just to add to the accepted answer, the use of interfaces or embedding is not really a requirement, at least not in this simple example.

For example, if you have a set of types that have the same structure but do not have any methods, i.e. pure data without behaviour, in such a case you can use a single type to represent the set and an additional "enum" to represent the "kind".

For example:

```
type AnimalKind string

const (
    AnimalKindDog AnimalKind = "dog"
    AnimalKindCat AnimalKind = "cat"
)

type Animal struct {
    Kind  AnimalKind
    Color string
}

// ...

dog := &Animal{Kind: AnimalKindDog, Color: "brown"}
tom := &Person{Name: "Tom", Age: 13, Pet: dog}
```